# Align items in middle in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a html code and i want to align theme like the image below:
[aligned image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08CIg.png)

My html code:

```
<button class="container">
    <span class="btn__img"></span>
    <span class="btn__txt">Basic</span>
</button>
```

Comment: `display:flex;flex-direction:column;` You can get more information from the [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) layout.

Comment: Or alternatively, you can change the span elements to be [block](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1.

You can use a [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) layout with column direction.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="container">
    Button
    <span class="btn__img">First Span</span>
    <span class="btn__txt">Second Span</span>
</button>
```

Method 2.

You can use the [display:block](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) for the spans to achieve this.

```css
.container span {
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="container">
    Button
    <span class="btn__img">First span</span>
    <span class="btn__txt">Second span</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; // if you want to align it center vertically 
    align-items: center; // if you want to align it center horizontally
}
```

Apply this css to your button.